# Cool Terminal words

Tags: macos, mac, unix, terminal

I've always seen awesome terminal prompt words or what ever you call them like the one below.

Does anyone know of a utility that can make text like this?

```
              ___       ___       ___       ___       ___
             /\  \     /\  \     /\  \     /\  \     /\  \
            /::\  \   /::\  \   /::\  \   /::\  \   /::\  \
           /::\:\__\ /:/\:\__\ /:/\:\__\ /:/\:\__\ /:/\:\__\
           \;:::/  / \:\/:/  / \:\ \/__/ \:\ \/__/ \:\/:/  /
            |:\/__/   \::/  /   \:\__\    \:\__\    \::/  /
             \|__|     \/__/     \/__/     \/__/     \/__/
```

Comment: http://www.glassgiant.com/ascii/

Comment: http://www.network-science.de/ascii/

Answer (score 15):

[Figlet](http://www.figlet.org/) is the standard utility for this.

```
$ echo 'stackoverflow' | figlet
     _             _                        __ _               
 ___| |_ __ _  ___| | _______   _____ _ __ / _| | _____      __
/ __| __/ _` |/ __| |/ / _ \ \ / / _ \ '__| |_| |/ _ \ \ /\ / /
\__ \ || (_| | (__|   < (_) \ V /  __/ |  |  _| | (_) \ V  V / 
|___/\__\__,_|\___|_|\_\___/ \_/ \___|_|  |_| |_|\___/ \_/\_/  

$ echo 'test' | figlet -f ./isometric1.flf 
      ___           ___           ___           ___     
     /\  \         /\  \         /\  \         /\  \    
     \:\  \       /::\  \       /::\  \        \:\  \   
      \:\  \     /:/\:\  \     /:/\ \  \        \:\  \  
      /::\  \   /::\~\:\  \   _\:\~\ \  \       /::\  \ 
     /:/\:\__\ /:/\:\ \:\__\ /\ \:\ \ \__\     /:/\:\__\
    /:/  \/__/ \:\~\:\ \/__/ \:\ \:\ \/__/    /:/  \/__/
   /:/  /       \:\ \:\__\    \:\ \:\__\     /:/  /     
   \/__/         \:\ \/__/     \:\/:/  /     \/__/      
                  \:\__\        \::/  /                 
                   \/__/         \/__/
```

Comment: Figlet is available on MacPorts for easy installation.

Answer (score 0):

There is another project on linux which supports FIGlet's fonts and mostly commandline-compatible with it.
A [TOIlet](http://caca.zoy.org/wiki/toilet) :)

But I didn't tried it on mac.