# Font Size In Shell Script

Tags: macos, shell-script

On execution of my script I want the font size of few echo commands to be bigger than the other things displayed. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In plain text mode there's no standard way to get bigger fonts, I think. Many terminal emulators support colors and this may be used to distinguish some text.

However you can build large characters with regular characters. To do this use [`figlet`](http://www.figlet.org/) (and see [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/188371)).

```
$ figlet "Super User"
 ____                          _   _               
/ ___| _   _ _ __   ___ _ __  | | | |___  ___ _ __ 
\___ \| | | | '_ \ / _ \ '__| | | | / __|/ _ \ '__|
 ___) | |_| | |_) |  __/ |    | |_| \__ \  __/ |   
|____/ \__,_| .__/ \___|_|     \___/|___/\___|_|   
            |_|
```

There's also [`toilet`](http://caca.zoy.org/wiki/toilet) (see [this](http://macappstore.org/toilet/)).

```
$ toilet "Super User"

  mmmm                                     m    m                     
 #"   " m   m  mmmm    mmm    m mm         #    #  mmm    mmm    m mm 
 "#mmm  #   #  #" "#  #"  #   #"  "        #    # #   "  #"  #   #"  "
     "# #   #  #   #  #""""   #            #    #  """m  #""""   #    
 "mmm#" "mm"#  ##m#"  "#mm"   #            "mmmm" "mmm"  "#mm"   #    
               #                                                      
               "
```

Refer to their manuals and search web for graphics to see what these tools can do. Your search query should be like `linux toilet` instead of plain `toilet` for obvious reason.

Compare also [this question](https://superuser.com/q/162383/432690).

---

If you want your text to be even fancier then check this out:

```
$ figlet "Hello World!" | cowsay -n
 ________________________________________________________
/  _   _      _ _        __        __         _     _ _  \
| | | | | ___| | | ___   \ \      / /__  _ __| | __| | | |
| | |_| |/ _ \ | |/ _ \   \ \ /\ / / _ \| '__| |/ _` | | |
| |  _  |  __/ | | (_) |   \ V  V / (_) | |  | | (_| |_| |
| |_| |_|\___|_|_|\___/     \_/\_/ \___/|_|  |_|\__,_(_) |
\                                                        /
 --------------------------------------------------------
        \   ^__^
         \  (oo)\_______
            (__)\       )\/\
                ||----w |
                ||     ||
```

Of course you need to install `cowsay` first.

Comment: Yes, i was aware about this but in Mac terminal this does not work. So i was curious is there any out for MacOs as well

Comment: @Prashast I thought you can install these tools for Mac, can't you? Or you're telling me you can but they don't work?

Comment: Sorry for the comment. I can install figlet on MacOs. Earlier I was using brew as root user so it was not allowing me to do.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [ASCII art](http://osxdaily.com/2014/05/23/create-ascii-art-text-banner/) (well, ANSI art, now). There are [sites that will process your text](http://www.network-science.de/ascii/) for you, too. Just echo each line separately.

For example, an error message:

[image: Error Message ASCII Art]

Comment: For predefined text this is just perfect. I would save to a file and just `cat` it when needed.